# How set cookies in dev tools in Google Chrome 98 version?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-devtools

after update google chrome up to 98 version, I can't set cookies[image]

it looks like a red stripe and after the refresh, it disappears. Even you fill all fields, it disappears.

Maybe any know how it disables the feature?
This feature describes in their [blog](https://blog.chromium.org/), but I can't find how to fix it

Comment: I just ran into this as well - looks like a bug has been filed w/ Chrome: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1293815

Comment: Well, the Chromium community say that they fixed the issue:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1290196 If that's true, then we have to wait for the update 99.

Comment: This is not a programming question; this should be closed as off-topic. if it is a programming question, it needs a [mcve].

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Based on the comment in this diff - https://chromium.googlesource.com/devtools/devtools-frontend/+/20ed4f2bd282537f404af9d45df1333d5aeb21f5%5E%21/#F0, I felt this has something to do with Partitioned cookies. So I opened **chrome://flags** and set the value of "**Partitioned Cookies**" to Enabled" and relaunched the browser. After that the red row did not appear and I am able to set the cookies like before.

Comment: Thanks; that was it for me. Seems like a pretty big bug to let slip through into a release.

Answer (score 19):

A workaround we are using for now is using the console to run `document.cookie='key=value'`.

It's not nearly as robust *but* it gets the cookie in and we can edit the other fields afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

Using a plugin like 'EditThisCookie' also works for now.

[image: screen shot of cookie editor]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: using that plugin did not work for me. When i created a new cookie it didn't save it.