# Why my Chrome Devtools can't change cookies value?

Tags: cookies, web-inspector

My Chrome Devtools can't change cookies value, when I change value and hit enter (red bar show) and if I refresh page it will become the same.
[My Chrome Devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrSdL.png)

But with my Firefox Developer tools I can change cookie value.
[My Firefox Developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qyzec.png)

** Sorry for my bad English **

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70973901/how-set-cookies-in-dev-tools-in-google-chrome-98-version?noredirect=1&lq=1